# Как разрешить публиковать записи с постороннего домена на свой сайт?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-плагины, wordpress-multisite

Помогите решить задачу.
Мой сайт размещен на определенном домене ( допустим site.com ), на другом сайте ( допустим **new-site.ru** ) нужно вывести форму создания постов, которые будут публиковаться на моем сайте (site.com) . Возможно ли сделать такую связку ?

Answer (score 1):

да,

1. делаете api
2. делаете api авторизацию

и стандартным REST API можете пулять сами себе данные

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
$(function() { 
 $.ajax( { 
 url: 'https://new-site.com/index.php/wp-json/ajaxposts/v1/post/', 
 method: 'GET',
 dataType: 'json'  
 } ).done( function ( response ) { 
 console.log( response ); 
 response.forEach(function(post){ 

var postdate = moment(post.post_date).format('D MMMM YYYY');

var posturl = "https://new-site.com/" + post.post_name;  
 
 
  $('#Post').append(` 
    <div class="post"> 
      <img src="${post.image}" /> 
      <span class="categoryTeg">${post.post_category_name[0].name}</span> 
      <h3><a href="${posturl}">${post.post_title}</a></h3> 
    </div> 
  `); 
}); 
} ); 
});
```

HTML вставить туда, где необходимо добавить посты с другого домена:

```
<div id="Post"></div>
```

При этом у вас должны быть настроены заголовки `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` со списком довереных доменов, по умолчанию (доступ разрешен любым доменам).

Comment: Вы запили описать как данный статьи вытащить из сайта1 один и написали как получить и вывести посты на сайт2

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно в файле function.php блога вставить данный код

```
function  ajax_endpoint( $request_data ) {
    $params = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 3, //количество последних опубликованных статей
      'order'=> 'DESC',
      'orderby' => 'date' 
    );
    
    $posts = get_posts($params);
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
        $posts[$key]->image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post, 'full' );
        $posts[$key]->author_name = get_user_by( 'ID', $posts[$key]->post_author );
        $posts[$key]->post_category_name = get_the_category( $posts[$key]->ID );
    }
    return  $posts;
}
    
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'ajaxposts/v1', '/post/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'ajax_endpoint'
    ));
});
```

а затем вставить в js файл на сайт в котором вы собираетесь выводить свои посты как написал Станислав в своем ответе

```
$(function() { 
    $.ajax( { 
        url: 'https://quickblox.com/blog/index.php/wp-json/ajaxposts/v1/post/', 
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'  
    } ).done( function ( response ) { 
        console.log( response ); 
        response.forEach(function(post){ 
     
     
        // var dd = Date.parse(post.post_date); 
        // var now = new Date(dd); 
        // var postdate = now.format("dd mmm yyyy"); 

        var postdate = moment(post.post_date).format('D MMMM YYYY');
        
        var posturl = "https://quickblox.com/blog/" + post.post_name;  
     
     
          $('#BlogPost').append(` 
            <div class="post"> 
              <img src="${post.image}" /> 
              <span class="categoryTeg">${post.post_category_name[0].name}</span> 
              <h3><a href="${posturl}">${post.post_title}</a></h3> 
              <span class="name">${post.author_name.data.display_name}</span> 
              <div class="oval"></div> 
              <span class="date">${postdate}</span> 
            </div> 
          `); 
        }); 
    } ); 
});
```